# web javascript - transition delay

Tags: javascript, transition

I am animating the entry transition of two elements in a web project. The transition in the Javascript file can be found underneath. I have not provided all code, I think this is a very specific question for a code check. If you want all the code I can provide it..

Two elements, "right_Groot" and "right_Klein", question is about the transition of "right_Klein". This is a transition with two separate animated properties. There is a move to the right and a rotation.

I would like to experiment with the transition delay on the rotation, so that I can see what is the most appealing delay. This is not functioning..

```
function Right_Entry(e){

if (window.scrollY > 1050){

    right_Groot.style.right ="20vw";
    right_Groot.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition", "right 1s linear");
    right_Groot.style.setProperty("transition", "right 1s linear");

    right_Klein.style.right = "35vw";
    right_Klein.style.transform = "rotate(-135deg)";

    right_Klein.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition-property", "right, transform");
    right_Klein.style.setProperty("transition-property", "right, transform");

    right_Klein.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition-duration", "1s, 1s");
    right_Klein.style.setProperty("transition-duration", "1s, 1s");

    right_Klein.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition-timing-function" ,"linear, linear");
    right_Klein.style.setProperty("transition-timing-function", "linear, linear");

    //delay is not reacting
    right_Klein.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition-delay", "0, 2s");
    right_Klein.style.setProperty("transition-delay", "0, 2");
}
}
```

So this is the part which is not functioning:

```
    //delay is not reacting
    right_Klein.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition-delay", "0, 2s");
    right_Klein.style.setProperty("transition-delay", "0, 2");
```

What is wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Different animation transitions names/values for different browsers, e.g. Chrome vs Safari vs. Mozilla

Comment: ok thanks for remark, I will adapt that, but the rest of the code is functioning.. that is the reason that I do not think this is the reason for malfunction..

Comment: I have found it! I missed "s" from seconds after the "0".. So "0s" instead of "0"..

Answer (score 0):

**Remark 1:**
I needed to add code for all browsers..

**Remark 2:**
    //delay is not reacting
    right_Klein.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition-delay", "0, 2s");
    right_Klein.style.setProperty("transition-delay", "0, 2");

changed to.. 
    right_Klein.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition-delay", "0s, 2s");
    right_Klein.style.setProperty("transition-delay", "0s, 2s");